# Using the Intermediate Value Theorem to prove a statement about an equation true

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-writing

I want to prove this statement true by using the IVF:

**For any real number $b > 2$, the equation $2^x = bx$ has a solution.**

Here are some questions I need help with answering:

1. Define a function $f(x) = 2^x-bx$. How does finding a zero for $f(x)$ correspond to finding a solution to $2^x=bx$? (I know that $f(x)$ is continuous, but don't understand what the correlation is).
2. Find a value $x$, when plugging it into $f$ gives a positive output, regardless of the value of the variable $b$, and
3. Find a value $x$ when plugged into $f$, gives a negative output, as long as $b > 2$.

Comment: $f(x)=0\implies 2^x=bx$ using the limit at $+\infty$ you see function is positive and negative for $x=1$

Comment: @kingW3 I get the part with the limit, but I need to find a value of X that always gives a positive regardless of b, and one that gives a negative output as long as b > 2. I'm sort of stumped here

Comment: The limit when $x\to\infty$ is $+\infty$ so you know there is a positive value for some x,and as i said $x=1$ gives negative

Comment: @kingW3, ok x = 1 gives negative, but what will always give a positive output, regardless of b? Sorry, but I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: You can't find such $x$ but you can ensure such $x$ exists since taking the limit of $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ then because of the IVF you can see that there is some $t$ for which $f(t)>0$